# Can you combine a c# variable with html tag name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing a foreach loop where I am outputting some HTML.  I need to change the name of an input element each time it goes through the loop.  I know in PHP it is super easy to combine text with a PHP variable.  I cannot figure out how to do this in C#.  I am using MVC3 Razor.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/subtract.png")" alt="Subtract" class="qtyminus" field="qtyValue@i" />
```

All this code does is print out "qtyValue@i".  It does not interpret the value of @i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using parentheses around the variable you're trying to output.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/subtract.png")" alt="Subtract" class="qtyminus" field="qtyValue@(i)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/subtract.png")" alt="Subtract" class="qtyminus" field="qtyValue@(i)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you will not have the expected output as it's considered as a string 
try this

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/subtract.png")" alt="Subtract" class="qtyminus" field="qtyValue"+ @i />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/subtract.png")" alt="Subtract" 
class="qtyminus" 
field=@string.Format(@"""qtyValue{0}""",i) />
```